# React Navigation: Dynamic Title Does Not Change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to dynamically change the title of my `react-navigation` navigation bar:

```
componentDidMount() {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => 
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ title:"New Title" });
  });
}
```

Although I can verify this function is called, the navigation bar does not change to "New Title."

Am I passing the wrong object into the `setParams()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

react navigation doesn't read the title from the `params` object. It uses the `navigationOptions` static property on the component.

You can set that property to a function:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    title: navigation.state.params.title
}
```

Then when you set the param the title should change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you avoid an error when the app first loads on the first screen in the navigation stack and the object navigation.state.params.title is undefined?

Comment: You can either pass initial params in the route definition (when creating the navigator), or just test for it in the `navigationOptions` code, and have a default value there.

Comment: Yes, what I ended up doing was adding logic to handle the case that the variable assigned to title was nonexistent and then returning a verified value for title.